# Convert XML to CSV using Pandas having multiple tag

Tags: python, pandas, xml, csv

There is a requirement to flatten XML file into CSV using python (Pandas) or any other libraries. i have multiple child tags underneath and one single header to be copied across child elements. This is my first programe in Python and unable to execute it successfully. Appreciate any direction here please

**- Expected Output from my input data.**

```
chName,envText,rptCod,rptNam,membId,membLglNam,rptPrntEffDat,rptPrntRunDat,membClgIdCod,membClgIdNam,clgCurrTypCod,poolId,currTypCod,membChgIdCod,membChgIdNam,acctTypFlexible,prtMgnUnadj,prtMgnReqt,ChgRat,totMgnClgCurr,sumChgMbrPrtgbReq,sumChgMbrClgCurr,sumPoolIdTotal,sumPoolIdClgCurr,sumClgMbrTotMgnClgCurr
DEBSIL,S,PTR001,DD01 Report,POP,ABC LT,08/04/2021,08/04/2021,UVBV,YEZZE,USD,POPXCLIENTECM,USD,POP123,ABC LT123,A1,5656.6,5634.6,1,34543.6,5656.6,5634.6,5656.6,5634.6,700090
DEBSIL,S,PTR001,DD01 Report,POP,ABC LT,08/04/2021,08/04/2021,UVBV,YEZZE,USD,POPXCLIENTNET,NZD,POP676,SEEN TD,A9,8989.9,45656.9,1,1780688.9,8989.9,45656.9,8989.9,45656.9,700090
DEBSIL,S,PTR001,DD01 Report,POP,ABC LT,08/04/2021,08/04/2021,UVBV,YEZZE,USD,POPXSTANDARD,MXM,POP343,ACMI,P1,345.5,4545.5,1,4545.5,345.5,4545.5,345.5,4545.5,700090
```

**Input data**

```
<PTR001>
<rptHdr>
    <chName>DEBSIL</chName>
    <envText>S</envText>
    <rptCod>PTR001</rptCod>
    <rptNam>DD01 Report</rptNam>
    <membId>POP</membId>
    <membLglNam>ABC LT</membLglNam>
    <rptPrntEffDat>2021-04-08</rptPrntEffDat>
    <rptPrntRunDat>2021-04-08</rptPrntRunDat>
</rptHdr>

<ptr001Grp>
    <ptr001KeyGrp>
        <membClgIdCod>UVBV</membClgIdCod>
        <membClgIdNam>YEZZE</membClgIdNam>
    </ptr001KeyGrp>
    <clgCurrTypCod>USD</clgCurrTypCod>
    <ptr001Grp1>
    <ptr001KeyGrp1>
        <poolId>CSBXCLIENTECM</poolId>
        <currTypCod>USD</currTypCod>
    </ptr001KeyGrp1>
    <ptr001Grp3>
        <ptr001KeyGrp3>
            <membChgIdCod>POP123</membChgIdCod>
            <membChgIdNam>ABC LT123</membChgIdNam>
        </ptr001KeyGrp3>
        <ptr001Rec>
            <acctTypFlexible>A1</acctTypFlexible>
            <prtMgnUnadj>5656.60</prtMgnUnadj>
            <prtMgnReqt>5634.60</prtMgnReqt>
            <ChgRat>1.000000</ChgRat>
            <totMgnClgCurr>34543.60</totMgnClgCurr>
        </ptr001Rec>

        <sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>5656.60</sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>
        <sumChgMbrClgCurr>5634.60</sumChgMbrClgCurr>
    </ptr001Grp3>

    <sumPoolIdTotal>5656.60</sumPoolIdTotal>
    <sumPoolIdClgCurr>5634.60</sumPoolIdClgCurr>
    </ptr001Grp1>

    <ptr001Grp1>
        <ptr001KeyGrp1>
            <poolId>POPXCLIENTNET</poolId>
            <currTypCod>NZD</currTypCod>
        </ptr001KeyGrp1>
    <ptr001Grp3>
        <ptr001KeyGrp3>
            <membChgIdCod>POP676</membChgIdCod>
            <membChgIdNam>SEEN TD</membChgIdNam>
        </ptr001KeyGrp3>
        <ptr001Rec>
            <acctTypFlexible>A9</acctTypFlexible>
            <prtMgnUnadj>8989.90</prtMgnUnadj>
            <prtMgnReqt>45656.90</prtMgnReqt>
            <ChgRat>1.000000</ChgRat>
            <totMgnClgCurr>1780688.90</totMgnClgCurr>
        </ptr001Rec>
        <sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>8989.90</sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>
        <sumChgMbrClgCurr>45656.90</sumChgMbrClgCurr>
    </ptr001Grp3>

    <sumPoolIdTotal>8989.90</sumPoolIdTotal>
    <sumPoolIdClgCurr>45656.90</sumPoolIdClgCurr>

    </ptr001Grp1>

    <ptr001Grp1>
        <ptr001KeyGrp1>
            <poolId>POPXSTANDARD</poolId>
            <currTypCod>MXM</currTypCod>
        </ptr001KeyGrp1>
    <ptr001Grp3>
        <ptr001KeyGrp3>
            <membChgIdCod>POP343</membChgIdCod>
            <membChgIdNam>ACMI</membChgIdNam>
        </ptr001KeyGrp3>
        <ptr001Rec>
            <acctTypFlexible>P1</acctTypFlexible>
            <prtMgnUnadj>345.50</prtMgnUnadj>
            <prtMgnReqt>4545.50</prtMgnReqt>
            <ChgRat>1.000000</ChgRat>
            <totMgnClgCurr>4545.50</totMgnClgCurr>
        </ptr001Rec>
        <sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>345.50</sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>
        <sumChgMbrClgCurr>4545.50</sumChgMbrClgCurr>
    </ptr001Grp3>
    <sumPoolIdTotal>345.50</sumPoolIdTotal>
    <sumPoolIdClgCurr>4545.50</sumPoolIdClgCurr>
    </ptr001Grp1>
    <sumClgMbrTotMgnClgCurr>700090.00</sumClgMbrTotMgnClgCurr>

</ptr001Grp>

</PTR001>
```

```
# Importing the required libraries
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd
  
cols = ["poolId", "currTypCod", "membChgIdCod", "membChgIdNam", "acctTypFlexible", "prtMgnReqt", "prtMgnReqt", "ChgRat", "totMgnClgCurr", "sumChgMbrPrtgbReq", "sumChgMbrClgCurr", "sumPoolIdTotal", "sumPoolIdClgCurr"]
rows = []
  
# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse = Xet.parse('myReport.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()
for i in root:
    poolId = i.find("poolId").text
    currTypCod = i.find("currTypCod").text
    membChgIdCod = i.find("membChgIdCod").text
    membChgIdNam = i.find("membChgIdNam").text
    acctTypFlexible = i.find("acctTypFlexible").text
    prtMgnReqt = i.find("prtMgnReqt").text
    ChgRat = i.find("ChgRat").text
    totMgnClgCurr = i.find("totMgnClgCurr").text
    sumChgMbrPrtgbReq = i.find("sumChgMbrPrtgbReq").text
    sumChgMbrClgCurr = i.find("sumChgMbrClgCurr").text
    sumPoolIdTotal = i.find("sumPoolIdTotal").text
    sumPoolIdClgCurr = i.find("sumPoolIdClgCurr").text
    
    rows.append({"poolId": poolId,
                 "currTypCod": currTypCod,
                 "membChgIdCod": membChgIdCod,
                 "membChgIdNam": membChgIdNam,
                 "acctTypFlexible": acctTypFlexible,
                 "prtMgnReqt": prtMgnReqt,
                 "ChgRat": ChgRat,
                 "totMgnClgCurr": totMgnClgCurr,
                 "sumChgMbrPrtgbReq":  sumChgMbrPrtgbReq,
                 "sumChgMbrClgCurr": sumChgMbrClgCurr,
                 "sumPoolIdTotal": sumPoolIdTotal,
                 "sumPoolIdClgCurr": sumPoolIdClgCurr})
  
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
  
# Writing dataframe to csv
df.to_csv('myReport.csv')
```

Comment: You forgot to post your XML. You also have to show what you've tried.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel - I've been trying since morning but not make it :( .. this is first Python

Comment: Well, at least you have to show that you tried to get the values out of the XML file.

Comment: This was I tried but found below error \n  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Please edit the __full text__ of the error message ino your question __as text__.   If any of your `i.find(…)` fails it will return None and then you get that error. Check your find values against your XML?

Comment: File "D:\Python\myReport.py", line 12, in <module>
    poolId = i.find("poolId").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Well, you don't appear to understand the hierarchical structure of your XML.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the sorting of the CSV columns for you to figure out. A search here in SO should yield numerous posts.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
<PTR001>
    <rptHdr>
        <chName>DEBSIL</chName>
        <envText>S</envText>
        <rptCod>PTR001</rptCod>
        <rptNam>DD01 Report</rptNam>
        <membId>POP</membId>
        <membLglNam>ABC LT</membLglNam>
        <rptPrntEffDat>2021-04-08</rptPrntEffDat>
        <rptPrntRunDat>2021-04-08</rptPrntRunDat>
    </rptHdr>
    <ptr001Grp>
        <ptr001KeyGrp>
            <membClgIdCod>UVBV</membClgIdCod>
            <membClgIdNam>YEZZE</membClgIdNam>
        </ptr001KeyGrp>
        <clgCurrTypCod>USD</clgCurrTypCod>
        <ptr001Grp1>
            <ptr001KeyGrp1>
                <poolId>CSBXCLIENTECM</poolId>
                <currTypCod>USD</currTypCod>
            </ptr001KeyGrp1>
            <ptr001Grp3>
                <ptr001KeyGrp3>
                    <membChgIdCod>POP123</membChgIdCod>
                    <membChgIdNam>ABC LT123</membChgIdNam>
                </ptr001KeyGrp3>
                <ptr001Rec>
                    <acctTypFlexible>A1</acctTypFlexible>
                    <prtMgnUnadj>5656.60</prtMgnUnadj>
                    <prtMgnReqt>5634.60</prtMgnReqt>
                    <ChgRat>1.000000</ChgRat>
                    <totMgnClgCurr>34543.60</totMgnClgCurr>
                </ptr001Rec>
                <sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>5656.60</sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>
                <sumChgMbrClgCurr>5634.60</sumChgMbrClgCurr>
            </ptr001Grp3>
            <sumPoolIdTotal>5656.60</sumPoolIdTotal>
            <sumPoolIdClgCurr>5634.60</sumPoolIdClgCurr>
        </ptr001Grp1>
        <ptr001Grp1>
            <ptr001KeyGrp1>
                <poolId>POPXCLIENTNET</poolId>
                <currTypCod>NZD</currTypCod>
            </ptr001KeyGrp1>
            <ptr001Grp3>
                <ptr001KeyGrp3>
                    <membChgIdCod>POP676</membChgIdCod>
                    <membChgIdNam>SEEN TD</membChgIdNam>
                </ptr001KeyGrp3>
                <ptr001Rec>
                    <acctTypFlexible>A9</acctTypFlexible>
                    <prtMgnUnadj>8989.90</prtMgnUnadj>
                    <prtMgnReqt>45656.90</prtMgnReqt>
                    <ChgRat>1.000000</ChgRat>
                    <totMgnClgCurr>1780688.90</totMgnClgCurr>
                </ptr001Rec>
                <sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>8989.90</sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>
                <sumChgMbrClgCurr>45656.90</sumChgMbrClgCurr>
            </ptr001Grp3>
            <sumPoolIdTotal>8989.90</sumPoolIdTotal>
            <sumPoolIdClgCurr>45656.90</sumPoolIdClgCurr>
        </ptr001Grp1>
        <ptr001Grp1>
            <ptr001KeyGrp1>
                <poolId>POPXSTANDARD</poolId>
                <currTypCod>MXM</currTypCod>
            </ptr001KeyGrp1>
            <ptr001Grp3>
                <ptr001KeyGrp3>
                    <membChgIdCod>POP343</membChgIdCod>
                    <membChgIdNam>ACMI</membChgIdNam>
                </ptr001KeyGrp3>
                <ptr001Rec>
                    <acctTypFlexible>P1</acctTypFlexible>
                    <prtMgnUnadj>345.50</prtMgnUnadj>
                    <prtMgnReqt>4545.50</prtMgnReqt>
                    <ChgRat>1.000000</ChgRat>
                    <totMgnClgCurr>4545.50</totMgnClgCurr>
                </ptr001Rec>
                <sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>345.50</sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq>
                <sumChgMbrClgCurr>4545.50</sumChgMbrClgCurr>
            </ptr001Grp3>
            <sumPoolIdTotal>345.50</sumPoolIdTotal>
            <sumPoolIdClgCurr>4545.50</sumPoolIdClgCurr>
        </ptr001Grp1>
        <sumClgMbrTotMgnClgCurr>700090.00</sumClgMbrTotMgnClgCurr>
    </ptr001Grp>
</PTR001>
'''

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
header = tree.find('rptHdr')
hd = {}
for c in header:
    hd[c.tag] = c.text.strip() if c.text else ''

group = tree.find('ptr001Grp')
gpaths = ['ptr001KeyGrp/*', 'clgCurrTypCod', 'sumClgMbrTotMgnClgCurr']
gd = {}
for x in gpaths:
    for c in group.findall(x):
        gd[c.tag] = c.text.strip() if c.text else ''

rows = []

dpaths = [
    'ptr001KeyGrp1/poolId', 'ptr001KeyGrp1/currTypCod',
    'ptr001Grp3/ptr001KeyGrp3/*', 'ptr001Grp3/ptr001Rec/*',
    'ptr001Grp3/sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq', 'ptr001Grp3/sumChgMbrClgCurr'
]
for e in group.findall('ptr001Grp1'):
    d = {}
    for x in dpaths:
        for c in e.findall(x):
            d[c.tag] = c.text.strip() if c.text else ''
    d.update(gd)
    d.update(hd)
    rows.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

print(df[['poolId', 'currTypCod', 'sumChgMbrPrtMgbReq', 'sumChgMbrClgCurr']])

import sys

df.to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False)
```

Comment: thanks Justin. however it's just repeating same block for 3 times.

Comment: Great, this works perfect. thank you .. let me check few things